# dealing with differents webbrowsers and cookies

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm telled to do a bank app with only webviews in my WP7 app. the first view is the authentification, when it's done and ok, the webView recieves tokens in cookies that I have to get. 
My first problèm is that I don't know how to detect it's ok.. the uri changed after authentification but it's the same if it's ok or not..
I don't know how to get the content of the webView, when i fired a Navigated event, e.Content is null..

then I have to pass the tokens to a panorama view with 5 WebBrowser using it. I understood that i could only add cookies via a httpRequest, and then put the result in webViews with NavigateToString, but if I do so the cookies will not be added to the webbrowser itself right ? So each redirection inside it will be errors ?

So what I understand is, that I have to intersept redirection with Navigating event, do a httpWebRequest, then set the content to my webbrowser ??

And I suppose I'll also lose my CSS ?

Please help me, I feel I'm going the wrong way..

Comment: is there any DocumentReady or DocumentLoaded event ?

Comment: wich control fire this event ?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to write an app which is essentially wrapping a man-in-the-middle approach to content interception. And a panorama hosting 5 separate web browsers sounds like a horrible visual and usability experience. It seems like you're trying to do a lot of things that you don't understand or why you should be doing them. I recommend going back to basics and not ask such a broad question.

Comment: Well, I simply don't have a choice... my ergonomist will be please to hear that the experience is crap, but it's like that, I just have to do what i'm told to.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Navigated` event on your WebBrowser control.

Example:

```
webBrowser.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(webBrowser_Navigated);



    void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Also, for getting reading the cookies, use the `GetCookies()` method to get the collection of cookies in the `Navigated` event. I have not tried adding cookies, but you can try using the `Add` method of the `CookieCollection` that you get back from `GetCookies()`. This should let you "transfer" the cookies from one WebBrowser to the others.

Here is a bit more documentation on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowserextensions.getcookies%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's impossible to add cookie to a webBrowser.. I am only able to get them